# How to place target="_blank" in pug

Tags: javascript, pug

I have the following links in a pug file:

```
 a.button.expanded(href=`${projects[id].live_link}`) Live Demo
        a.button.expanded(href=`${projects[id].github_link}`) GitHub Repo
```

I am trying to add target=_blank" like this

```
a.button.expanded(href=`${projects[id].live_link}target="_blank"`) Live Demo
```

but that does not seem to be working, can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `,` to separate attributes

> Tag attributes look similar to HTML (with optional commas), but their values are just regular JavaScript.

Doc : [Pug - Attributes](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html)

so,

```
a.button.expanded(href=`${projects[id].live_link}`, target="_blank") Live Demo
```

Comment: You can always ask them as separate questions with necessary code snippets. :) #Soreadytohelp

Comment: I fixed the problem nvm